# Alignment of qtgraphics items in qt graphics scene

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics

I have a graphics view which contains a scene with some graphics items. How can I make those graphics items appear on the left side of the scene and not in the center ?

I have looked through many ideas but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add an invisible `QGraphicsRectItem` as the first item.

Then add other items as children of that first item.

The center of the first item is the center of the coordination.

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(widget.graphicsView);

// ....

QGraphicsRectItem *frame = scene->addRect(-100,-100,100,100);
frame->setPen(Qt::NoPen);

// ....

// Add new items as children of frame
// Align them relative to their parent
```

```
                           ^
                           |
                           |
        -100,100           |            100,100
            +-----------------------------+
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
---------------------------+------------------------>
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            |              |              |
            +-----------------------------+
        -100,100           |            100,-100
                           |
```

To make it aware to window size, override these methods:

```
class MainForm : public QMainWindow
{
//...

QGraphicsScene *scene;     // Move it here
QGraphicsRectItem *frame;  // Move it here

protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event);
    virtual bool event(QEvent * event);
    virtual void resizeAction();
//...
};

void MainForm::resizeAction()
{
    QRectF rect(field->rect());
    widget.graphicsView->setSceneRect(rect);
    widget.graphicsView->fitInView(rect, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}

void MainForm::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
{
    resizeAction();
    QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}

bool MainForm::event(QEvent * event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Show)
        resizeAction();

    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Comment: I want when you resize the window have the graphics items also follow the left side. If I resize the window they lose their initial alignment and eventually appear in the center.

Comment: The problem here is that my graphic item is magnified as the window size increases.

Comment: Comment the line contains `fitInView` and check if it's OK ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
Scene_item.setSceneRect(x0,y0,x1,y1);
```